# Can't connect to mysql over ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am trying to connect to a MariaDB database (v 5.5.52) that is running on port 3306 on a CentOS (v 7.3.1611) box
For security reasons the server's port 3306 is firewalled (`telnet mysite.com 3306` times out)

Because I can ssh into the server with a configured connection:

`ssh projectx`

and then connect to the database:

`mysql -u remote -p
use staff;`

I am expecting this connection in Sequel Pro to get me connected from my laptop:

[image]

But I am getting this error message:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
>   MySQL said: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

The user has these grants:

`` show grants for 'remote'@'%';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for remote@%                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'remote'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'redacted'             |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP ON `staff`.* TO 'remote'@'%'  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ ``

And I have this in the [mysqld] section of my.cnf

`bind-address = *`

No errors logged in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log

Comment: Are you sure that your software **actually uses** ~/.ssh/config? // Nevermind - it seems it does: https://sequelpro.com/docs/get-started/get-connected/remote

Comment: @Xatenev good thought, but yes, I have connected to other servers like this without problem.

Comment: You wrote 'you can ssh into the server with a configured configuration' => Does that mean you are trying to connect to a 3rd party server? In that case, MysQL Host 127.0.0.1 would be wrong and should be replaced by the server IP (I think so atleast? - not 100% sure on that1).

Comment: @Xatenev that is true if you use the "Standard" connection tab. Because the remote server only has ports 80, 443 and 22 open, the ssh configuration gets me connected to the server and then I connect to mysql form the "inside", thus the loopback address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define a remote user `@'%'` if you are using an SSH connection. You also don't need to bind any interface other than 127.0.0.1, since you are essentially connecting from the local machine.

Anyway, `bind-address` should `127.0.0.` in your case (for connecting from localhost). To get MySQL to bind to all interfaces you need `0.0.0.0` (but again, this is not needed if you ssh).

Also make sure that MySQL is configured to use TCP and not a local unix socket. Try ssh-ing into the machine and running `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 ...`. If this doesn't work and `mysql -h localhost` works, the server is setup to use a unix socket.

The remote `sshd` daemon must be setup so that it allows port forwarding. Add the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Comment: I can ssh in and successfully connect with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u remote -p` and I have also created and tried the "narrower" user 'remote'@'127.0.0.1' but no success.

Comment: Can you try something like `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@remote-server`? Then try connecting locally on your machine `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 ...`. This turns connections into the local 3306 port to connections to the remote's 3306 port. This is what Sequel Pro is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: I get the same error, but this time with a error number: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0` which I can Google. Thanks so far!

Comment: Please update here if you have a solution -- for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: After some Googling the two things that are suggested was to increase the connection timeout (it is now 20 seconds and still fails) and making changes to `/etc/hosts.allow`  I have added `mysqld: ALL` and `mariadb: ALL` but without success

Comment: Just for debugging: on the remote machine run `netstat -an |grep 3306` and make sure you see `127.0.0.1:3306   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN`. This means that mysqld is listening on 3306. Next, after you run `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 xxx@yyy` on your local machine: open another terminal and try connecting to that socket using netcat: `nc localhost 3306`. On my machine I get something like the following: `5.5.5-10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.11N...` (the remote is ubuntu running MariaDB).

Comment: netstat on the remote shows that the service is listening on port 3306 (same output as yours). However, on the last command (`nc localhost 3306`) I get this error message: `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`

Comment: Perhaps try adding `AllowTcpForwarding yes` to the server's sshd config file?

Comment: Also seems like you need `PermitTunnel yes` (It's the default, so just make sure sshd_config doesn't have it set to "no")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145468/discussion-between-jannie-theunissen-and-nimrodm).

Comment: GREAT! AllowTcpForwarding yes did it!! Can you please add that to your answer so I can accept it. Well done!